# Tomcat SSL not available outside

Tags: ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate, https

I do have a Tomcat8 server running, currently in the development environment. It's been working for a while on the port we have picked (8085) and was available outside of our network (unblocked on the firewall). Recently we have made decision to run https also. I did configure our certificate and added connector directive for SSL in `server.xml`.

Unfortunately it's not working as expected. SSL is working perfectly fine when I try to open it via remote desktop browser (in fact - on the localhost) it work both on `https://localhost:8443` and `https://domain.com:8443`. 
Until this point everything works fine and as expected but when we try to access it from the other network it's not working, just gives a time out when we try to access `https://domain.com:8443` but `http://domain.com:8085` works just fine outside.

We did think that it might be something with our firewall although we have decided to disable it for a while and it's still not working.

Any idea what might cause it?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />

  <GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8085" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />

    <Connector port="8443" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
        maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" alias="tomcat"
        keystoreFile="c:/cert_pn_2015.p12"
        keystorePass="PASS" 
        keystoreType="PKCS12"/>

    <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">

        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
               resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
      </Realm>

      <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
               pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are redirecting 8085 to 8443 which gives me the idea that 8443 is closed. When it reaches 8085 tomcat redirects the traffic internally on 8443(acts like a proxy). Do a telnet on 8443 and you will find out.

Please have a look here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: I must have not explain myself clearly. When I hit 8085 it does show me page over http. Doesn't do redirect.

Comment: Indeed and this is because of how the redirect page works for the Tomcat connector. Please have a look here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html. Will add it to the response

Comment: I did remove redirectPort from 8085 connector and it didn't help. The biggest problem is that it works while connecting from localhost. That's what I wonder why it doesn't work outside.

Comment: Go on another server( from where it does not work) and go with telnet hostname 8443. Does that work?

Comment: Looks like telnet works

Comment: Can you try to go by IP then? https://IP:8443 ?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine. But when I do telnet to 8085 and do GET / it returns page but it doesn't over 443. Makes me think that virtual box might be the reason behind it.

Comment: That or you have an proxy, something else that translates the DNS entry and makes it unavailable. I would say this is not a Tomcat issue.